# Rust libz_sys crate - Z_VERSION_ERROR?

Tags: rust, zlib

I'm using the libz_sys crate in a Rust project, and I have the following code (taken out of context):

```
let mut in_data = data.to_owned();
let mut next_out = Vec::with_capacity(in_data.len());
let msg = CString::new("").unwrap();
let mut state = mem::uninitialized();
let mut zstream = libz_sys::z_stream {
    next_in: in_data.as_mut_ptr(),
    avail_in: 0,
    total_in: 0,
    next_out: next_out.as_mut_ptr(),
    avail_out: 0,
    total_out: 0,
    msg: msg.into_raw(),
    state: &mut state,
    zalloc: mem::uninitialized(),
    zfree: mem::uninitialized(),
    opaque: mem::uninitialized(),
    data_type: 0,
    adler: 0,
    reserved: 0,
};
match libz_sys::inflateInit_(&mut zstream, libz_sys::zlibVersion(), data.len() as raw::c_int) {
    libz_sys::Z_OK => (),
    e => return Err(format!("Error decoding idat: Error code {}", e))
}
```

However when I run this code, `inflateInit_` is returning error code -6: Z_VERSION_ERROR, which indicates that the zlib.h version does not match the version of libz being linked against. Does anyone know if this is an expected error with this crate or how to fix it? The libz_sys crate has no documentation, however I can't use a higher-level crate like flate2 because I need the ability to pass compression options to libz. I'm developing on OS X 10.11 and Rust 1.7-nightly, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument of `inflateInit_()` is the size of the `z_stream` structure, not the length of the data.

Comment: Thanks, turns out that was the issue! I never would have guessed that from "version error".

Comment: It checks both the version string and the size of the z_stream struct to verify that the header and library match.